# Почему selectedUsers не присваивается значения из dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

```
    public partial class Users
    {
        public int User_Id { get; set; }
        public string User_Email { get; set; }
        public string User_Password { get; set; }
        public string User_Role { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
 partial class Users
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return User_Id + "" + User_Email + "" + User_Password + "" + User_Role;
        }
    }
```

---

```xml
 <DataGrid x:Name="UsersDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="125" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Initialized="UsersDataGrid_Initialized" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" SelectionChanged="UsersDataGrid_SelectionChanged" MouseUp="UsersDataGrid_MouseUp">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Код" Width="31"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Email}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Логин" Width="120"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Password}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Пароль" Width="80"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Role}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Роль" Width="91"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

---

```
 private void UsersDataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            
            var selectedUsers = UsersDataGrid.SelectedItems[0] as Users;

            if (selectedUsers != null)
            {
                TextBoxLoginOptions.Text = selectedUsers.User_Email;
                TextBoxPasswordOptions.Text = selectedUsers.User_Password;
                TextBoxRoleOptions.Text = selectedUsers.User_Role;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBoxLoginOptions.Text = "";
                TextBoxPasswordOptions.Text = "";
                TextBoxRoleOptions.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

---

```
  private void UsersDataGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var query = from user in entities.Users
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = user.User_Id,
                            Email = user.User_Email,
                            Password = user.User_Password,
                            Role = user.User_Role
                        };
            foreach (var user in query)
            {
                UsersDataGrid.Items.Add(user);
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Пробовал через Item]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Пробовал через Items]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему selectedUsers не присваивается значения из dataGrid

Класс Users это таблица из бд
Модель ADO.NET EDM

Comment: Потому что `SelectedItems` это не `Users`, а `IList<Anonymous Type>`. У вас же на экране всё, перед глазами. Еще `SelectedItems` это коллекция, а не элемент. То есть вам нужно что-то такое `SelectedItems[0]`.

Comment: Ничего не меняется

Comment: И не должно, проблема в том, что вы не показали, что такое Users, не показали как наполняете DataGrid, не показали настройки самой DataGrid в XAML разметке. Всё это надо вставить в вопрос текстом.

Comment: добавил, надеюсь будет понятно

Comment: ТЕКСТОМ! я не буду перепечатывать ваш код с картинки, чтобы попробовать. Класс Users покажите еще, тоже ТЕКСТОМ, а не скриншотом.

Comment: может так подойдет ?

Comment: `partial class Users` а где вторая часть класса? Я буду долго еще силой вытягивать из вас код или это все-таки вам больше надо решить проблему, а не мне? Уберите лишние скриншоты, а то уже перестаю понимать, что где.

Comment: Искренне не понимаю о какой второй части класса идет речь

Comment: Где свойства находятся. Вы же видите `partial`? Где свойства `User_Id`, `User_Email`, вот это вот всё?

Comment: `User_Id + "" + User_Email + ""` Поставьте курсор на `User_Id` и нажмите F12

Comment: спасибо, сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные нужно деананимизировать, иначе придется втыкать некрасивые костыли.

Создайте вьюмодель класса пользователя

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

далее вот так

```
private void UsersDataGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = from user in entities.Users select new UserViewModel
    {
        Id = user.User_Id,
        Email = user.User_Email,
        Password = user.User_Password,
        Role = user.User_Role
    };
    UsersDataGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToArray();
}
```

и вот так

```
private void UsersDataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedUser = UsersDataGrid.SelectedItem as UserViewModel;

    TextBoxLoginOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Email ?? string.Empty;
    TextBoxPasswordOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Password ?? string.Empty;
    TextBoxRoleOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Role ?? string.Empty;
}
```

---

Но есть способ проще.

В конструкторе окна сделайте так

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

И заведите свойство

```
private UserViewModel selectedUser;
public UserViewModel SelectedUser
{
    get => selectedUser;
    set
    {
        selectedUser = value;
        TextBoxLoginOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Email ?? string.Empty;
        TextBoxPasswordOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Password ?? string.Empty;
        TextBoxRoleOptions.Text = selectedUser?.Role ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

В XAML разметке

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="UsersDataGrid" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" ...>
```

А обработчик `UsersDataGrid_MouseUp` теперь нужно просто удалить.

Поздравляю, вы сделали свою первую одностороннюю привязку данных "контрол->модель". Изучите привязки данных, они достаточно мощный инструмент, кода придется писать намного меньше. Ну и почитайте про шаблон проектирования MVVM.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше терпение и ответ.

Comment: @Simp https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135478/373567 вот вам более правильный пример, как сделать то что нужно на двухсторонних привязках вообще без лишнего кода

Comment: не поможете с сохранением и удалением ? , вижу что по ссылке это есть но пока не совсем понимаю

Comment: и datagrid заполняется 2 раза в строку

Comment: @Simp разбирайтесь с привязками. То что не сразу доходит, это нормально, вы привыкли как винформах делать, WPF - совсем другое по подходу к разработке. Почитайте материалы про привязки данных и MVVM, станет полегче.