# Как передавать выбранную запись в DataGrid между страницами и окнами?

Tags: c#, wpf

Не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос (не хватает опыта). Боюсь сделать ещё хуже. Поэтому просто напишу, что я хочу сделать, и что я уже сделал.

Например. Я создал модели классов ***employee*** и ***customers***. Они содержат атрибуты *name*, *age*, *phone* (ну и т.д.). Затем я вывел все записи классов в два *DataGrid* (*dgEmployee*, *dgCustomers*) окна ***MainWindow***.

Как мне передать/вывести, выбранную в одном из *DataGrid*'ов, запись в *textbox*'ы на странице ***page1***, которая вызывается из окна ***Window2*** после выбора записи и нажатия кнопки ***Add*** в ***MainWindow*** ?  При этом окно ***Window2*** также может иметь страницы ***page2,page3,page4***, которые выполняют совершенно другую работу, например обрабатывают классы cars, models и тому подобное (не имеет значения).

> По сути делаю приложения для редактирования таблиц c данными, где есть 2 окна - главное и второстепенное. На главном окне отображаются таблицы. Второстепенное окно выводит страницы, которые содержат в себе элементы для редактирования выбранной записи таблицы. Для каждой таблицы своя страница т.к. они очень разные (не такие, что в примере).

> Возможно, я вообще не правильно всё делаю. Дайте знать если это так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте коллекции и [привязки данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141941/373567).

Выбранный элемент [можно отслеживать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135478/373567) через созданный по умолчанию `CollectionView` при включенной настройке таблицы `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`, это поддерживается нативно привязками в формате `{Binding Collection/ItemProperty}`.

Comment: Это работает если элемент находится внутри окна/страницы. У меня элемент DataGrid создан в окне MainWindow.  page1, куда должна передаться запись, ничего не знает о DataGrid (dgEmployee и т.д.). Window2 где загружается старница page1 тоже ничего не знает о DataGrid (dgEmployee и т.д.).

Comment: @Pahomka Это работает хоть в 100 окнах. Вам всего-лишь надо иметь ссылку на одну и ту же коллекцию с данными, чтобы использовать привязку. Где там по каким окнам и страницам раскиданы контролы и таблицы - без разницы. Обратите внимание, вы используете `x:Name`, я дал примеры, где это не используется. Это индикатор того, что примеры вы не изучили пока. Не спешите тогда утверждать, что не работает.